# Is there a way to apply a filtered sets to all IDs in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

My data currently looks something like the below (plain text and image attached). In Tableau, I am able to create a Set that essentially says if the response to Q8 is 1, then add to the Set "Top Tier." If the response to Q8 is 2, then add to the Set "Second Tier."

I would like, however, to apply this across all of the IDs. So for example, I would like any row with an ID "A" to be labeled "Top Tier".

I am happy if this is in either sets or done with calculated fields.

Please let me know if you can help!

```
ID  Question    Response    Set
A   Q7  1   
B   Q7  1   
C   Q7  2   
A   Q8  1   Top Tier
B   Q8  2   Second Tier
C   Q8  2   Second Tier
```

[image]

Comment: So is your requirement to label each row with id as A, with top tier?

Comment: please add your desired output for each row, so that your can be understood better